# Uploaded homemade mp3 to icloud music library, now "not available in my country or region"

Tags: itunes, icloud, music, mp3, library

We recorded an mp3 with the kids, and I want to add this to my icloud music library so it's available on my iPhone and any of my devices, the same way I access other songs in my icloud music library that I've purchased from iTunes, etc.

I managed to add it to the library, then clicked "add song to icloud music library". How it shows up in my library on my phone. However, it now cannot be played and says "This song is not currently available in your country or region."

I only have one iTunes account and we've not left the country, etc. Is there a way to see an icloud music library dashboard where I can manage these things and resolve this dumb issue?

Comment: When I open the "Song Info" and go to "File" tab, it says iCloud Status: Waiting. I sense this could have something to do with it?

Answer (score 3):

Astonishingly the error had nothing to do with the "song not being available in my country or region," but simply was because the song had not yet loaded into the iCloud Music Library. I clicked on File, Library, Update iCloud Music Library, and after about 5 minutes, the song was available on my other devices.